# Identity insert few records without truncating to an existing table

Tags: sql-server, constraints, primary-key, unique-constraint, identity-insert

I would like to insert data from a table which is in A server from the B server.

ex:

```
select count(*) from A.table
-- 100 rows affected


delete from A.table where customer_code = '100'
-- 10 rows affected

select count(*) from B.table
-- 200 rows affected

select count(*) from B.table where customer_code='100'
-- 20 rows affected

both the tables have identity(1,1) and primary_key


insert into A.table(customer_key,customer_code,custome_name)
select customer_key,customer_code,custome_name  
    from B.table where customer_code='100'
```

> --Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint . Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'A.table'.

I have already tried

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <> ON
DBCC CHECKIDENT(<>, RESEED,0)
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

The Primary Key Violation is telling you that the at least one of the values for `customer_key` in `A.table` that you are trying to insert from `B.Table` is already in use for a different Customer record in `A` (and assuming that you've already run your delete statement for this `customer_code`).

This means it is already too late to consider trying to keep the surrogate identity column `customer_key` in synch between the two tables A and B (as you say you are not are in a position to truncate `A` and copy across from scratch from `B`, if applicable). However, it seems that `customer_code` does not provide unique identification (idempotence) of a customer either (since the delete removed 10 rows).

So in summary - if you don't need to establish any link other than by `customer_code`, and potentially via `customer_name`, you can copy the data into `A` which will be assigned new identity `customer_key`'s:

(i.e. leaving `IDENTITY_INSERT` OFF)

```
insert into A.table(customer_code,custome_name)
select customer_code,customer_name  
    from B.table where customer_code='100'
```

Otherwise, if you do need to uniquely identify rows between the tables, what you will need to do is add new storage for the link between the 2 tables. A quick and dirty way would be to add B's surrogate directly to A, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE A.table ADD customer_key_TableB INT NULL  -- Or whatever the type of `customer_key`
GO
```

Then insert and link the data like so (Again, with `IDENTITY INSERT` for Table A still off):

```
insert into A.table(customer_code, customer_name, customer_key_TableB)
select customer_code, customer_name, customer_key
    from B.table where customer_code='100'
```

Comment: Something has to give here. You either need to delete all the data on table `A..Customer` and reinsert from scratch (in which case, you may as well drop the identity on `A..Customer`, since it is driven from `B`), or otherwise you need to admit that it is impossible to merge the data into `A` and retain `B`'s surrogate id with the same value as the key for `A` as well, unless you drop the PK on A and allow duplicates.